# What does the word rectiplanar mean?

Tags: terminology

I have seen uses of the word 'rectiplanar' in some older math books but Google-ing doesn't really give an answer to its meaning. I have found though the following [patent application](https://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/.piw?PageNum=0&docid=08668756&IDKey=EBB97A352864&HomeUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpatft.uspto.gov%2Fnetacgi%2Fnph-Parser%3FSect1%3DPTO2%2526Sect2%3DHITOFF%2526p%3D1%2526u%3D%25252Fnetahtml%25252FPTO%25252Fsearch-bool.html%2526r%3D1%2526f%3DG%2526l%3D50%2526co1%3DAND%2526d%3DPTXT%2526s1%3D20130199143%2526OS%3D20130199143%2526RS%3D20130199143) where this word is mentioned and defined, but I am struggling to understand exactly what that means. The excerpt from the application is this:

> In figs 1-10, the panel filter element 38 is rectiplanar, i.e. lies in a single two-dimensional plane which is rectilinear in each of such two dimensions.

[image]

**Figure : fig 3 from the patent application which shows element 38**

The link I have provided has these figures as well. This definition mentions that the element lies in a two-dimensional plane, but most of these pictures are 3-d. On figures 4 and 5 the panel filter element 38 looks to me like a 3-d object, so how can it lie in a 2-dimensional plane? Can anyone help me understand this definition?

Comment: I am uncertain but I believe rectiplanar, comes from rectangular and planar, which means planes which are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Take the word in the figure for it, it is a plane formed by two linear axes. A filter is a 3D element with uniform thickness, thus can be seen as a 2D element with thickness.

Comment: @r13 what do you mean a 2d element with thickness?

Comment: @MichaelMunta A filter can be considered as a planar element bounded by lines with the third dimension (thickness) is uniform throughout. If the thickness varies, then it must be described as a 3D element though.

Comment: @r13 still not really sure what you mean. Can you provide an example of an object that couldn't be represented in 2d space?

Comment: Michael, r13 is saying that it just means that the filter is flat and rectangular in outline but (obviously) has a certain thickness. Other filters could be curved, cylindrical, spherical, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Other than the noted shapes, the rest can be simply drawn on a 2D plane with a note t, L, or h = xx, thus "rectilinear element" or "rectiplanar element".

Everything on the earth is 3D, but depends on the complicacy of its geometry, very often a 3D element is identified as a 2D element, such as a beam, a plate...

Can you represent/describe the whole element in Fig 3 on a single (2D) plan?
The answer obviously is you can, but you are going to "note the details" which requires more effort than you simply draw more plans.

Comment: What do you mean by "with a note t, L, or h = xx"?

Comment: Noting the thickness, length, or height of the 2D element with a number, instead of drawing another view other than the 2D plan.